# ApolloGraphQL PubSub: MaxListenersExceededWarning?

Tags: graphql, publish-subscribe, subscription, apollo

I'm using `graphql-postgres-subscriptions` to add pubsub to my ApolloGraphQL app. I'm seeing this in my server logs:

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 CallAdded listeners added.

- Is there a limit of 10 listeners per client? If so, my app only has 4
  subscriptions. I make sure they are only called once per component mount, and are unsubscribed on component unmount. How can I have 10 listeners for a given client?
- Is there a limit of 10
  listeners for the entire app? If so how can this function if I have
  hundreds of simultaneous users?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I'm not getting `MaxListenersExceededWarning` any more. Possibly when I unsubscribed to my graphQL subscription on component unmount that fixed it-- but I still got the `MaxListenersExceededWarning` warnings until I did a server reboot.

Anyway, so far things appear to be all good. If the anomaly recurs I will create a test case app.